# Fixing system boot

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, boot

**EDITED (provided screenshots for clarification):**

A while back I installed fedora 25, besides windows 10, on my laptop. The thing is, that now I have extra device and I want to remove dual boot (linux).

I deleted linux partitions, but I still have the booting options. I tried running recovery drive of windows 10 through USB, and in CMD wrote boortec /fixmbr and bootrec /fixboot. But every time I restart my device I get to chose system to boot.

So first after turning on my device I get lenovo loading screen. Right after that I am left with a black screen with booting options:
1.[Top left corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A93Vd.jpg)
2. [Bottom left corner corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8zUY.png)

Now when I deleted linux partitions it obviously cannot boot into fedora and every time I have to choose WBM.

How can I restore original windows 10 booting order?
I read that reinstallation of windows might help?

Answer (score 0):

Reinstallation won't be necessary - you can use the `bcdedit` command to work with the list of items in the Windows Boot Manager. The boot configuration store is separate from the MBR, which is why the fix commands you already tried didn't work. Windows helpfully will add new operating systems to the list, but not automatically remove them.

Here's how you clear out the errant entries:

1. Open an administrator command prompt
2. Run `bcdedit /enum`. You will see your extra Linux entries in there, probably by a long UUID like `{49916baf-0e08-11db-9af4-000bdbd316a0}`
3. Copy the problematic UUID corresponding to what you want to remove.
4. Run `bcdedit /delete (the UUID)`

The deleted option will be gone on next boot.

[Microsoft's documentation on `bcdedit`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/adding-boot-entries#adding-a-new-boot-entry-in-windows-vista-and-later) indicates that you may need to disable secure boot or bitlocker if you are using them before this will work.

Comment: I don't think I bcdedit /enum worked they way you thought it would. Can you look at the output I've got? I don't see any linux entries there.

Answer (score 0):

There is a clue in this line:

> I looks something like: - Fedora (...) - Fedora (...) - Fedora (rescue...) - Windows Boot Manager

This means you are not yet inside the Windows Boot Manager where BCDEdit can reach.

It sounds like you are looking at something in the BIOS\UEFI.

Try the answer from this thread:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi

PASTE FROM OTHER THREAD:

> You should be able to do this via a Live Ubuntu CD.
>
> Install efibootmgr:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install efibootmgr
> ```
>
> Then add to the kernel efi support
>
> ```
> sudo modprobe efivars
> ```
>
> Then run sudo efibootmgr to check your boot entries. It will return
>   something like this:
>
> ```
> BootCurrent: 0004
> Timeout: 2 seconds
> BootOrder: 2001,0003,0005,0006,0000
> Boot0000* Lenovo Recovery System
> Boot0001* EFI Network 0 for IPv6 (B8-88-E3-84-F3-EF)
> Boot0002* EFI Network 0 for IPv4 (B8-88-E3-84-F3-EF)
> Boot0003* Windows Boot Manager
> Boot0004* EFI USB Device (SanDisk)
> Boot0005* ubuntu
> Boot2001* EFI USB Device
> ```
>
> Then delete the option you dont want. In this example, Ubuntu is entry
>   5. the following could be called to delete entry 5 and remove it from the BootOrder.
>
> (CAUTION: Before executing the following command make sure you enter
>   the correct Boot entry number)
>
> ```
> sudo efibootmgr -b 5 -B
> ```
>
> Further details described here: http://linux.die.net/man/8/efibootmgr
>
> Note: as for anything that changes your bootloader, please ensure you
>   have a good disk image that you can boot with.
>
> Now you should also delete the ubuntu subdirectory in the EFI
>   partition to prevent the UEFI firmware from restoring the entry into
>   the BootOrder.
>
> To do that, first find your EFI partition. Run sudo fdisk -l to see
>   the partitions on all attached drives. The EFI partition has EFI
>   Partition under the Type column.
>
> Suppose your EFI partition was /dev/sda2, then mount it on an empty
>   folder anywhere.
>
> ```
> sudo mkdir /mnt/efipart
> sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/efipart
> ```
>
> Now we have to find the directory Ubuntu or any other distro's name in
>   this partition. It is mostly under EFI/distro_name.
>
> Remove that directory and its contents by (PLEASE MAKE SURE YOU ARE
>   DELETING THE CORRECT DIRECTORY) sudo rm -r ubuntu.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: Seems redundant to paste verbatim the answer from a different StackExchange site. It also makes my post look overly verbose. Before it was a simple pointer and now it's a duplication.

Comment: It's not redundant. The other answer may be deleted, for whatever reason.

Comment: However, please read [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing). You must block quote text that has been written by some else. See [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help). I've fixed it for you this time, but please pay attention to this in future.

Comment: You can take a look at the screenshots. They suggest that I'm in the bios. So is your solution still aplicable?

Comment: The instructions I gave was an example of how to remove the entries from the BIOS menu. Was that not clear? P.S. I don't see any screenshots here.